# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost: XXXX is therefore not allowed access

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-identity

I am working with David Antaramian's [spa-authentication-example](https://bitbucket.org/david.antaramian/so-21662778-spa-authentication-example/overview). I followed his example explicitly with the exception that I using an n-tier approach and separated my Data/Models from the Web API project.

When using Postman and targeting the API web app directly, everything works fine:

[image]

But not when I use the client UI (I did change the url's in the angularjs' user.js/salesdata.js to reflect the 2604 port), not so good:

[image]

I tried "app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);" in my Startup.Auth.cs to no avail.

Also tried in my API web.config, still no good:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <!-- Enable Cross Domain AJAX calls -->
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Thinking perhaps it was a Chrome related security issue, I also tried it in IE, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Here is my complete post method, it is identical to Postman:

```
this.authenticate = function(username, password, successCallback, errorCallback, persistData) {
  this.removeAuthentication();
  var config = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:2604/token',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: 'grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password,
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial:

> You should be able to use an HTTP request tool (my vote is for Postman) to make a call to the API. What you'll need to do is make a POST to localhost:{port}/token with x-www-form-urlencoded data of the form "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password"

You are not setting the xss prevention data "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password" anywhere in your http request.

So, in the code where you make an HTTP POST, one way to properly send the correct parameters is to just append the xss prevention data to the url. Like so:

```
localhost:2604/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password
```

Be sure to set username=(the correct username)&password=(the correct password)

Personally, I have also used os_authType=basic instead of grant_type=password. grant_type is what the author suggests, so try that first.

Comment: DID NOT WORK:   this.authenticate = function(username, password, successCallback, errorCallback, persistData) {
      this.removeAuthentication();
      var config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:2604/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password',

Comment: Please post your full POST method. Did you get the exact same error when you tried to append the ?grant_type...(ect).

Comment: see above for full post method

Answer (score 0):

**In a fit of total rage, I performed an "update-package" and now things work. Perhaps I had conflicting Newtonsoft packages in my various apps.**